# Comparing JSON files and removing the duplicate IP address subnets

Tags: python-3.x, bash

I have 2 JSON files - file1.json and file2.json. I need to compare both the files and remove the duplicates from file2.json. Can we do this using Bash or Python?

file1.json

```
{

  "Name": "LAN IPS LAN1",
  "Networks": [
    "10.33.28.0/27",
    "10.33.28.32/28",
    "10.33.28.48/30",
    "10.33.28.52/31",
    "10.33.28.55/32",
    "10.33.28.56/29",
    "10.33.28.64/26",
    "10.33.28.128/26",
    "10.33.28.192/28",
    "10.33.28.208/29",
    "10.33.28.216/30",
    "10.33.28.222/31",
    "10.33.28.224/27",
    "10.33.29.0/24",
    "10.33.30.0/23",
    "172.18.0.0/22",
    "172.20.4.0/22",
    "10.42.52.0/24",
    "10.97.30.0/29",
    "10.97.240.0/24",
    "10.97.160.0/24",

  ]

}
```

file21.json

```
{

  "Name": "LAN IPS LAN1",
  "Networks": [
    "10.33.28.0/27",
    "10.33.28.32/28",
    "10.33.28.48/30",
    "10.33.28.52/31",
    "10.33.28.55/32",
    "10.33.28.56/29",
    "10.33.28.164/26",
    "10.33.28.128/26",
    "10.33.28.192/28",
    "10.33.28.208/29",
    "10.33.28.216/30",
    "10.33.28.122/31",
    "10.33.28.224/27",
    "10.33.29.31/24",
    "10.33.30.50/23",
    "172.18.0.0/22",
    "172.20.4.0/22",
    "10.42.52.0/24",
    "10.97.30.0/29",
    "10.97.240.0/24",
    "10.97.160.0/24",

  ]

}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is neither a code writing service nor a replacement for basic documentation and tutorials. There are numerous articles on reading JSON with Python, etc. Show us the code with which you have tried to solve this problem, explain where you're having difficulty, and we would be happy to help out.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
import json


with open("file1.json", "r") as JSONfile:
    data1 = json.load(JSONfile)

with open("file2.json", "r") as JSONfile:
    data2 = json.load(JSONfile)
    
data2["Networks"] = list(filter(lambda x: x not in data1["Networks"], data2["Networks"]))

with open("file2.json", "w") as JSONfile:
    json.dump(data2, JSONfile)
```

Comment: It is useful to wait with the answer until the questioner has shown what he has done to answer the question himself.